# How can I retrieve data from multiple rows in the same column from database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm a newbie to programming and Laravel. I'm trying to fetch data from 3 rows that belong to one column called "name" in "users" table. The current table, called **"requisitions"** has a **foreign key** relationship with **"users"** table and it ("requisitions" table) has these 3 columns which get data from "users": "requisitioner_id", "approver_id" and "disbursor_id".

Earlier, I was using the following code to display "id" and it worked just fine:

```
<td>{{$requisition->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->requisitioner_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->file->file}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->expense_cat->expense_cat}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->amount}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->details}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->req_date}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->approval_status->approval_status}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->amt_approved}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->approver_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->approval_date}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->disb_status->disb_status}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->amt_disbursed}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->disbursor_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->date_disbursed}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->note}}</td>
```

Here was my index method in controller:

```
 public function index()
{
    //
    $requisitions = Requisition::all();
    return view('requisitions.index', compact('requisitions'));
}
```

Now, I'm trying to show requisitioner, approver and disbursor **names** instead of **id** but I'm getting this error:

[Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.disbursor_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`disbursor_id` = 1 limit 1) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lexmaxter\resources\views\requisitions\index.blade.php)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKJas.png)

while using this in blade:

```
   @foreach($requisitions as $requisition)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$requisition->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->file->file}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->expense_cat->expense_cat}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->amount}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->details}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->req_date}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->approval_status->approval_status}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->amt_approved}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->approval_date}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->disb_status->disb_status}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->amt_disbursed}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->date_disbursed}}</td>
        <td>{{$requisition->note}}</td>
        <td>
```

Requisition Model:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['expense_cat_id', 'file_id', 'requisitioner_id', 'approval_status_id', 'approver_id', 'disb_status_id', 'disbursor_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'amount', 'details', 'req_date', 'amt_approved', 'approval_date', 'amt_disbursed', 'date_disbursed', 'note'];

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'approver_id','disbursor_id','requisitioner_id');
}
```

User Model:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function requisition()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Requisition');
}
```

First, how can I resolve this issue and display the requisitioner, approver and disbursor names correctly?

Secondly, why does the code work for columns such as 'file' and 'expense_cat'? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you are getting the error because `disbursor_id` column is not there in your users table.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for pointing that out. How can I display the name correctly for each record without having to create a "disbursor_id" column in users because I don't want to create a 'disbursors' table?

Comment: What column in your `users` table should match the `disbursor_id` column from your requisitions table?

Comment: @droopsnoot It should just be `name`. All disbursors, approvers and requisitioners should be found in the `users` in a column called `name`. A user can be a disbursor, approver or requisitioner.

Comment: But if you want to link it, there must be a unique id - each user row should have a name and an id, and the id should be stored in any other table that wishes to refer to it. By the sound of it, your `disbursor_id` column in the requisitioners table refers to the id in the users table.

Comment: Correct. `disbursor_id` refers to the `id` in `users` table. This id needs to be used in the `approver_id` and `requisitioner_id` columns of `requisitions` table. I can create 3 separate tables for approvers, disbursors and requisitioners and use their ids for their respective columns in the `requisitions`  table, but I only want to use just one table for all three - i.e  `users` - and that's where I'm stuck.